# precision vs accuracy java floating point number

Tags: java

According to the following site: Precision vs. accuracy. Precision = tightness of specification. Accuracy = correctness.  Do not confuse precision with accuracy.  http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/91float/

Can someone please define and then explain what is the difference between is precision and accuracy in relation to java floating point numbers

Comment: Who said there's a difference?

Comment: They are synonyms.

Comment: Precision vs. accuracy. Precision = tightness of specification. Accuracy = correctness.  Do not confuse precision with accuracy.  http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/91float/

Comment: Why is this question being down voted ?

Comment: Precision and accuracy are not the same. Don't listen to those who claim they're synonyms. The answers, and @Shivam Sinha's comment, are right about the difference.

Comment: Needs more up votes, this is a great question and apparently it isn't being asked enough...

Answer (score 5):

Precision is the number of digits you specify, while accuracy specifies the difference from the true result.

To give an example:

3.14 is less precise than 3.149 but more accurate if it is considered the value of pi.

A Java `float` has a precision of about 6-7 decimal digits. It depends on the accuracy of the inputs and the numerical stability of the algorithm how accurate the result is you get.

Comment: from an algorithmic perspective, one might say that accuracy is how deeply to calculate the value and precision is where to round it

Answer (score 2):

If you go through the documentation of [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), it describes about single and double **precision** types. It says that *"Nearly all hardware and programming languages use floating-point numbers in the same binary formats".*

The usual formats are 32 or 64 bits in total length:

> **Format:** Single Precision
>
> **Total Bits:** 32
>
> **Significant Bit:** 23 + 1 sign
>
> **Exponent Bits:** 8
>
> **Smallest Number:** ca. 1.2 ⋅ 10(pow)-38
>
> **Largest Number:** ca. 3.4 ⋅ 10(pow)38
>
> ---
>
> **Format:** Double Precision
>
> **Total Bits:** 64
>
> **Significant Bit:** 52 + 1 sign
>
> **Exponent Bits:** 11
>
> **Smallest Number:** ca. 5.0 ⋅ 10(pow)-324
>
> **Largest Number:** ca. 5.0 ⋅ 10(pow)-324

Java follows this single and double precision types supported by keywords.

```
float f = 0.1f; // 32 bit float, note f suffix

double d = 0.1d; // 64 bit float, suffix optional
```

If `strictfp` keyword is used on classes, interfaces, methods, it will force all the intermediate results to follow **IEEE 754** values as well as it guarantees identical results **(Accuracy)** on all platforms. Without the `strictfp` keyword, implementations can use an extended exponent range where available, resulting in more precise results and faster execution on many common CPUs.

So, being the user / programmer, one can specify the precision (Rounding off value).

Example:

```
String.format("%.2f", 3.2399) // returns "3.24"
String.format("%.3f", 3.2399) // returns "3.240"
```

And accuracy is something which defines the degree to which a calculation or specification conforms to the **correct value or a standard**.

For more details you can have a look at [Java SE Specifications](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/)